# "IntelliTrace is not collecting data for this debugging session" message with WCF and IIS

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I am getting the message below in IntelliTrace tab when debugging a WCF service hosted by IIS on Windows 7 SP1 64bit. I tried [this tip](http://continuouslyintegrating.blogspot.com/2011/05/windows-7-sp1-iis-and-intellitrace.html) but it didn't help. It seems like a catch 22 situation. IntelliTrace doesn't work if process (w3wp.exe) is already running but to get the breakpoint to hit, I need to attach to the running w3wp.exe process. All the code is in the same solution. Any ideas how to get IntelliTrace working when attaching to IIS? If this doesn't work, I might have to debug using the internal Web server where it can start when the WCF service is called.

**Message:**
IntelliTrace is not collecting data for this debugging session.
The project type may not be supported or the process you are debugging may have been either attached to or launched with IntelliTrace disabled. Restarting the debugging session within Visual Studio may solve this. Please note that IntelliTrace is not supported when attaching to a process that is already running.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure multiple startup projects so that your front-end project as well as the WCF project both start during a debug session you should have no problems.

Configure multipl startup project off of the solution context menu.

Comment: Did you step into the WCF services and open the intellitrace window while in the service?  At what point are you trying to view the IntelliTrace data for WCF?

Comment: I launch the debugger in the WCF service method called by the client. I use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();